# Kubernetes - traefik external ip stuck in pending

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I spun a two node cluster in AWS and installed traefik using helm. I see that the service external IP is stuck at pending status. Checked several sources but couldn't find anything to resolve the issue. ANy help is appreciated

```
helm install stable/traefik



ubuntu@ip-172-31-34-78:~$ kubectl get pods -n default
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
unhinged-prawn-traefik-67b67f55f4-tnz5w   1/1     Running   0          18m
ubuntu@ip-172-31-34-78:~$ kubectl get services -n default
NAME                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
kubernetes               ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      55m
unhinged-prawn-traefik   LoadBalancer   10.102.38.210   <pending>     80:30680/TCP,443:32404/TCP   18m
ubuntu@ip-172-31-34-78:~$ kubectl describe service unhinged-prawn-traefik
Name:                     unhinged-prawn-traefik
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=traefik
                          chart=traefik-1.52.6
                          heritage=Tiller
                          release=unhinged-prawn
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=traefik,release=unhinged-prawn
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.102.38.210
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30680/TCP
Endpoints:                10.32.0.6:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               httpn/TCP
NodePort:                 https  32404/TCP
Endpoints:                10.32.0.6:8880
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

ubuntu@ip-172-31-34-78:~$ kubectl get svc unhinged-prawn-traefik --namespace default -w
NAME                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
unhinged-prawn-traefik   LoadBalancer   10.102.38.210   <pending>     80:30680/TCP,443:32404/TCP   24m
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you installed your cluster, but basically, the `kube-controller-manager/kubelet/kube-apiserver` cannot talk to the AWS API to create a load balancer to serve traffic for your [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

- It could be just as simple as your instance missing the required [instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) with the permissions to create a load balancer and routes.
- It could also that you need to add this flag to all your kubelets, your kube-apiserver, and your kube-controller-manager:

  ```
  --cloud-provider=aws
  ```
- It could also be that you are missing these [EC2 tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html) on your instances:

  ```
  KubernetesCluster=<yourclustername>
  kubernetes.io/cluster/kubernetes=owned
  k8s.io/role/node=1
  ```

Note that you might also need the `KubernetesCluster=<yourclustername>` tag on the subnet where your nodes are on.

- It could also be that your K8s nodes don't have a `ProviderID:` spec that looks like this:

  ```
  ProviderID: aws:///<aws-region>/<instance-id>
  # You can add it with kubectl edit <node-name>
  ```

Note that the `--cloud-provider` flag is being deprecated in favor of the [Cloud Providers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/) controller.

Comment: thanks Rico. SOrry about the delayed reply. The issue was related to IAM permission to create load balancers.

Comment: @IT_novice what permissions did you need to add to resolve the issue?